# how to check if we are in single post and check the category of single post?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to use different `css` file for one of my categories post in `wordpress`, for example I want hook different `css` files for post of news category.
How can I do this, I search a lot but find nothing.
I use f`unctions.php` and `wp_queue_style` for adding `css` files to my theme.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `is_category()` fucntion like this.

```
function include_theme_scripts(){
if(is_category('news') && is_singular(array('post', 'page'))){
        wp_enqueue_style('cat_style',get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/css/catstyle.css');
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'include_theme_scripts');
```

Check the documentation for the [is_category()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_category/)